# How to properly validate input values with React.JS?

Tags: javascript, validation, input, reactjs

I have a simple form. All of the components and state are held in the Page component. There are 2 display headers and 3 input fields. The first input is supposed to be text, and the second and third are supposed to be ints. When the user inputs the wrong type of data, I want to have an error message pop up next to the input field. My questions relate to best practices in React.JS

Who decides that the value is in valid? I suppose that the only job of the input field is to direct the value back to component holding the state, so does this mean that only Page can determine if a value is valid?

How should I then have the pop up appear? Should Page have to trigger a new boolean state element that will be passed through perp that will tell Adaptive_Input to reveal the error message?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/easilyBaffled/bgC6E/1/)

**JS:**

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */
var Adaptive_Input = React.createClass({ 
    handle_change: function(){
        var new_text = this.refs.input.getDOMNode().value;
        this.props.on_Input_Change(new_text);
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
                <div className='adaptive_placeholder_input_container'>
                    <input 
                        className="adaptive_input"
                        type="text" 
                        required="required" 
                        onChange= {this.handle_change}
                        ref="input"
                    ></input>
                    <label
                        className="adaptive_placeholder"
                        alt={this.props.initial}
                        placeholder={this.props.focused}
                    ></label>
                </div>              
                );
    }
});

var Form = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
                <form>
                    <Adaptive_Input
                        initial={'Name Input'}
                        focused={'Name Input'}
                        on_Input_Change={this.props.handle_text_input}
                    />
                    <Adaptive_Input
                        initial={'Value 1'}
                        focused={'Value 1'}
                        on_Input_Change={this.props.handle_value_1_input}
                    />
                    <Adaptive_Input
                        initial={'Value 2'}
                        focused={'Value 2'}
                        on_Input_Change={this.props.handle_value_2_input}
                    />
                </form>
                );
    }
});

var Page = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            Name : "No Name",
            Value_1 : '0',
            Value_2 : '0',
            Display_Value: '0'
        };
    },
    handle_text_input: function(new_text){
        this.setState({
                Name: new_text
            });
    },
    handle_value_1_input: function(new_value){
        console.log("===");
        var updated_display = parseInt(new_value) + parseInt(this.state.Value_2);
        updated_display = updated_display.toString();
        this.setState({
                Display_Value: updated_display 
            });
    },
    handle_value_2_input: function(new_value){
        var updated_display = parseInt(this.state.Value_1) + parseInt(new_value);
        updated_display = updated_display.toString();
        this.setState({
                Display_Value: updated_display
            });
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
                <div>
                    <h2>{this.state.Name}</h2>
                    <h2>Value 1 + Value 2 = {this.state.Display_Value}</h2>
                    <Form
                        handle_text_input={this.handle_text_input}
                        handle_value_1_input = {this.handle_value_1_input}
                        handle_value_2_input = {this.handle_value_2_input}
                    />
                </div>
        );
    }
});

React.renderComponent(<Page />, document.body);
```

Comment: This would be a good read? http://christianalfoni.github.io/javascript/2014/10/22/nailing-that-validation-with-reactjs.html

Comment: If using Node, a simple solution is using [react-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-validation) from npm.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

First, here is an example of what I'll mention below: http://jsbin.com/rixido/2/edit

How to properly validate input values with React.JS?

However you want. React is for rendering a data model. The data model should know what is valid or not. You can use Backbone models, JSON data, or anything you want to represent the data and it's error state.

More specifically:

React is generally agnostic towards your data. It's for rendering and dealing with events.

The rules to follow are:

1. elements can change their state.
2. they cannot change props.
3. they can invoke a callback that will change top level props.

How to decide if something should be a prop or a state? Consider this: would ANY part of your app other than the text field want to know that the value entered is bad? If no, make it a state. If yes, it should be a prop.

For example, if you wanted a separate view to render "You have 2 errors on this page." then your error would have to be known to a toplevel data model.

Where should that error live?
If your app was rendering Backbone models (for example), the model itself would have a validate() method and validateError property you could use. You could render other smart objects that could do the same. React also says try to keep props to a minimum and generate the rest of the data. so if you had a validator (e.g. https://github.com/flatiron/revalidator) then your validations could trickle down and any component could check props with it's matching validation to see if it's valid.

It's largely up to you.

(I am *personally* using Backbone models and rendering them in React. I have a toplevel error alert that I show if there is an error anywhere, describing the error.)

Comment: 'React also says try to keep props to a minimum' - Do you know where React documents this?

Comment: "Figure out what the absolute minimal representation of the state of your application needs to be and compute everything else you need on-demand." http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html Step 3

Comment: Shouldn't it be "React also says try to keep state to a minimum"?

Comment: @MosesLee Using props instead of component state keeps state to a minimum per component. Calculating derived values in render calls instead of storing them, keeps props (and state) to a minimum. We are trying to keep state to a minimum in both senses, and props at a minimum in the second sense.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `npm install --save redux-form`

Im writing a simple email and submit button form, which validates email and submits form. with redux-form, form by default runs event.preventDefault() on html onSubmit action.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  onSubmit(props) {
    //do your submit stuff
  }


  render() {
    const {fields: {email}, handleSubmit} = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email"
               className={`form-control ${email.touched && email.invalid ? 'has-error' : '' }`}
          {...email}
        />
          <span className="text-help">
            {email.touched ? email.error : ''}
          </span>
        <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function validation(values) {
  const errors = {};
  const emailPattern = /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/;
  if (!emailPattern.test(values.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Enter a valid email';
  }

  return errors;
}

LoginForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'LoginForm',
  fields: ['email'],
  validate: validation
}, null, null)(LoginForm);

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: So what? People still coming to this question and if there is a new approach to address the problem, why not? Redux or not - it's totally valid.

Answer (score 4):

Your jsfiddle does not work anymore.
I've fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/tkrotoff/bgC6E/40/ using React 16 and ES6 classes.

```
class Adaptive_Input extends React.Component {
  handle_change(e) {
    var new_text = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.props.on_Input_Change(new_text);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="adaptive_placeholder_input_container">
        <input
          className="adaptive_input"
          type="text"
          required="required"
          onChange={this.handle_change.bind(this)} />
        <label
          className="adaptive_placeholder"
          alt={this.props.initial}
          placeholder={this.props.focused} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <Adaptive_Input
          initial={'Name Input'}
          focused={'Name Input'}
          on_Input_Change={this.props.handle_text_input} />

        <Adaptive_Input
          initial={'Value 1'}
          focused={'Value 1'}
          on_Input_Change={this.props.handle_value_1_input} />

        <Adaptive_Input
          initial={'Value 2'}
          focused={'Value 2'}
          on_Input_Change={this.props.handle_value_2_input} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Name: 'No Name',
      Value_1: '0',
      Value_2: '0',
      Display_Value: '0'
    };
  }

  handle_text_input(new_text) {
    this.setState({
      Name: new_text
    });
  }

  handle_value_1_input(new_value) {
    new_value = parseInt(new_value);
    var updated_display = new_value + parseInt(this.state.Value_2);
    updated_display = updated_display.toString();
    this.setState({
      Value_1: new_value,
      Display_Value: updated_display
    });
  }

  handle_value_2_input(new_value) {
    new_value = parseInt(new_value);
    var updated_display = parseInt(this.state.Value_1) + new_value;
    updated_display = updated_display.toString();
    this.setState({
      Value_2: new_value,
      Display_Value: updated_display
    });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.Name}</h2>
        <h2>Value 1 + Value 2 = {this.state.Display_Value}</h2>
        <Form
          handle_text_input={this.handle_text_input.bind(this)}
          handle_value_1_input={this.handle_value_1_input.bind(this)}
          handle_value_2_input={this.handle_value_2_input.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And now the same code hacked with form validation thanks to this library: https://github.com/tkrotoff/react-form-with-constraints
=> http://jsfiddle.net/tkrotoff/k4qa4heg/

[image: http://jsfiddle.net/tkrotoff/k4qa4heg/]

```
const { FormWithConstraints, FieldFeedbacks, FieldFeedback } = ReactFormWithConstraints;

class Adaptive_Input extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    form: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      field: undefined
    };

    this.fieldWillValidate = this.fieldWillValidate.bind(this);
    this.fieldDidValidate = this.fieldDidValidate.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.context.form.addFieldWillValidateEventListener(this.fieldWillValidate);
    this.context.form.addFieldDidValidateEventListener(this.fieldDidValidate);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.context.form.removeFieldWillValidateEventListener(this.fieldWillValidate);
    this.context.form.removeFieldDidValidateEventListener(this.fieldDidValidate);
  }

  fieldWillValidate(fieldName) {
    if (fieldName === this.props.name) this.setState({field: undefined});
  }

  fieldDidValidate(field) {
    if (field.name === this.props.name) this.setState({field});
  }

  handle_change(e) {
    var new_text = e.currentTarget.value;
    this.props.on_Input_Change(e, new_text);
  }

  render() {
    const { field } = this.state;
    let className = 'adaptive_placeholder_input_container';
    if (field !== undefined) {
      if (field.hasErrors()) className += ' error';
      if (field.hasWarnings()) className += ' warning';
    }

    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <input
          type={this.props.type}
          name={this.props.name}
          className="adaptive_input"
          required
          onChange={this.handle_change.bind(this)} />
        <label
          className="adaptive_placeholder"
          alt={this.props.initial}
          placeholder={this.props.focused} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Name: 'No Name',
      Value_1: '0',
      Value_2: '0',
      Display_Value: '0'
    };
  }

  handle_text_input(e, new_text) {
    this.form.validateFields(e.currentTarget);

    this.setState({
      Name: new_text
    });
  }

  handle_value_1_input(e, new_value) {
    this.form.validateFields(e.currentTarget);

    if (this.form.isValid()) {
      new_value = parseInt(new_value);
      var updated_display = new_value + parseInt(this.state.Value_2);
      updated_display = updated_display.toString();
      this.setState({
        Value_1: new_value,
        Display_Value: updated_display
      });
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        Display_Value: 'Error'
      });
    }
  }

  handle_value_2_input(e, new_value) {
    this.form.validateFields(e.currentTarget);

    if (this.form.isValid()) {
      new_value = parseInt(new_value);
      var updated_display = parseInt(this.state.Value_1) + new_value;
      updated_display = updated_display.toString();
      this.setState({
        Value_2: new_value,
        Display_Value: updated_display
      });
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        Display_Value: 'Error'
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Name: {this.state.Name}</h2>
        <h2>Value 1 + Value 2 = {this.state.Display_Value}</h2>

        <FormWithConstraints ref={form => this.form = form} noValidate>
          <Adaptive_Input
            type="text"
            name="name_input"
            initial={'Name Input'}
            focused={'Name Input'}
            on_Input_Change={this.handle_text_input.bind(this)} />
          <FieldFeedbacks for="name_input">
            <FieldFeedback when="*" error />
            <FieldFeedback when={value => !/^\w+$/.test(value)} warning>Should only contain alphanumeric characters</FieldFeedback>
          </FieldFeedbacks>

          <Adaptive_Input
            type="number"
            name="value_1_input"
            initial={'Value 1'}
            focused={'Value 1'}
            on_Input_Change={this.handle_value_1_input.bind(this)} />
          <FieldFeedbacks for="value_1_input">
            <FieldFeedback when="*" />
          </FieldFeedbacks>

          <Adaptive_Input
            type="number"
            name="value_2_input"
            initial={'Value 2'}
            focused={'Value 2'}
            on_Input_Change={this.handle_value_2_input.bind(this)} />
          <FieldFeedbacks for="value_2_input">
            <FieldFeedback when="*" />
          </FieldFeedbacks>
        </FormWithConstraints>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

The proposed solution here is hackish as I've tried to keep it close to the original jsfiddle. For proper form validation with react-form-with-constraints, check https://github.com/tkrotoff/react-form-with-constraints#examples

Answer (score 3):

I have written [This library](https://github.com/vishalvisd/react-validator) which allows you to wrap your form element components, and lets you define your validators in the format :-

```
<Validation group="myGroup1"
    validators={[
            {
             validator: (val) => !validator.isEmpty(val),
             errorMessage: "Cannot be left empty"
            },...
        }]}>
            <TextField value={this.state.value}
                       className={styles.inputStyles}
                       onChange={
                        (evt)=>{
                          console.log("you have typed: ", evt.target.value);
                        }
                       }/>
</Validation>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **`onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "name")`** method and **`value={this.state.fields["name"]}`** on input text field and below that create span element to show error, see the below example.

```
export default class Form extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state ={
       fields: {
         name:'',
         email: '',
         message: ''
       },
       errors: {},
       disabled : false
    }
  }

  handleValidation(){
       let fields = this.state.fields;
       let errors = {};
       let formIsValid = true;

       if(!fields["name"]){
          formIsValid = false;
          errors["name"] = "Name field cannot be empty";
       }

       if(typeof fields["name"] !== "undefined" && !fields["name"] === false){
          if(!fields["name"].match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)){
             formIsValid = false;
             errors["name"] = "Only letters";
          }
       }

       if(!fields["email"]){
          formIsValid = false;
          errors["email"] = "Email field cannot be empty";
       }

       if(typeof fields["email"] !== "undefined" && !fields["email"] === false){
          let lastAtPos = fields["email"].lastIndexOf('@');
          let lastDotPos = fields["email"].lastIndexOf('.');

          if (!(lastAtPos < lastDotPos && lastAtPos > 0 && fields["email"].indexOf('@@') === -1 && lastDotPos > 2 && (fields["email"].length - lastDotPos) > 2)) {
             formIsValid = false;
             errors["email"] = "Email is not valid";
           }
      }

      if(!fields["message"]){
         formIsValid = false;
         errors["message"] = " Message field cannot be empty";
      }

      this.setState({errors: errors});
      return formIsValid;
  }

  handleChange(field, e){
      let fields = this.state.fields;
      fields[field] = e.target.value;
      this.setState({fields});
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(this.handleValidation()){
          console.log('validation successful')
        }else{
          console.log('validation failed')
        }
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} method="POST">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-25">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-75">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name"  refs="name" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "name")} value={this.state.fields["name"]}/>
                <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["name"]}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-25">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-75">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Email" refs="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "email")} value={this.state.fields["email"]}/>
                <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["email"]}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-25">
                <label htmlFor="message">Message</label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-75">
                <textarea type="text" placeholder="Enter Message" rows="5" refs="message" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "message")} value={this.state.fields["message"]}></textarea>
                <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["message"]}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <button type="submit" disabled={this.state.disabled}>{this.state.disabled ? 'Sending...' : 'Send'}</button>
          </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used redux-form and formik in the past, and recently React introduced Hook, and i have built a custom hook for it. Please check it out and see if it make your form validation much easier.

Github: https://github.com/bluebill1049/react-hook-form

Website: http://react-hook-form.now.sh

with this approach, you are no longer doing controlled input too.

example below:

```
import React from 'react'
import useForm from 'react-hook-form'

function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm() // initialise the hook
  const onSubmit = (data) => { console.log(data) } // callback when validation pass

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input name="firstname" ref={register} /> {/* register an input */}

      <input name="lastname" ref={register({ required: true })} /> {/* apply required validation */}
      {errors.lastname && 'Last name is required.'} {/* error message */}

      <input name="age" ref={register({ pattern: /\d+/ })} /> {/* apply a Refex validation */}
      {errors.age && 'Please enter number for age.'} {/* error message */}

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can have multiple fields with similar validation in your application. In such a case I recommend to create common component field where you keep this validation.

For instance, let's assume that you have mandatory text input in a few places in your application. You can create a TextInput component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
        touched: false, error: '', class: '', value: ''
    }
}

onValueChanged = (event) => {
    let [error, validClass, value] = ["", "", event.target.value];

    [error, validClass] = (!value && this.props.required) ? 
        ["Value cannot be empty", "is-invalid"] : ["", "is-valid"]

    this.props.onChange({value: value, error: error});

    this.setState({
        touched: true,
        error: error,
        class: validClass,
        value: value
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text"
                value={this.props.value}
                onChange={this.onValueChanged}
                className={"form-control " + this.state.class}
                id="{this.props.id}"
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder} />
            {this.state.error ?
                <div className="invalid-feedback">
                    {this.state.error}
                </div> : null
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

And then you can use such a component anywhere in your application:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: {firstName: '', lastName: ''},
        formState: {
            firstName: { error: '' },
            lastName: { error: '' }
        }
    }
}

onFirstNameChange = (model) => {
    let user = this.state.user;
    user.firstName = model.value;

    this.setState({
        user: user,
        formState: {...this.state.formState, firstName: { error: model.error }}
    })
}

onLastNameChange = (model) => {
    let user = this.state.user;
    user.lastName = model.value;

    this.setState({
        user: user,
        formState: {...this.state.formState, lastName: { error: model.error }}
    })
}


onSubmit = (e) => {
   // submit logic
}


render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <TextInput id="input_firstName"
                value={this.state.user.firstName}
                onChange={this.onFirstNameChange}
                required = {true}
                placeholder="First name" />

            <TextInput id="input_lastName"
                value={this.state.user.lastName}
                onChange={this.onLastNameChange}
                required = {true}
                placeholder="Last name" />

            {this.state.formState.firstName.error || this.state.formState.lastName.error ?
                <button type="submit" disabled className="btn btn-primary margin-left disabled">Save</button>
                : <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary margin-left">Save</button>
            }

        </form>
    )
}
```

Benefits:

- You don't repeat your validation logic
- Less code in your forms - it is more readable
- Other common input logic can be kept in component
- You follow React rule that component should be as dumb as possible

Ref. https://webfellas.tech/#/article/5

Answer (score 0):

I recently spent a week studying lot of solutions to validate my forms in an app. I started with all the most stared one but I couldn't find one who was working as I was expected. After few days, I became quite frustrated until i found a very new and amazing plugin:
https://github.com/kettanaito/react-advanced-form

The developper is very responsive and his solution, after my research, merit to become the most stared one from my perspective. I hope it could help and you'll appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

yet another go at the same problem - `form-container`
[on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-container)