# how to allow date in "dd/mm/yyyy" inside an input text field in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, validation, date, reactjs

Working on a sample reactjs form.
It has two date fields, `startdate` and `enddate` as shown below

```
<input type="text" name="startdate" value={this.state.startDate}/>
<input type="text" name="enddate" value={this.state.endDate}/>
```

these two fields should allow date, only in "dd/mm/yyyy" format and should not allow any other characters expect valid date, month, year and "/".

How to allow only the valid characters as mentioned above using javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly validate input values with React.JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019431/how-to-properly-validate-input-values-with-react-js)

Comment: @stdob my problem is not specific to reactjs, it about input field date format validation. if you can provide a link to fix the issue, it will be helpful. I searched but I didn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

If working only on a text field, use [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) to parse the field content and assert the format.

There is [node-dateformat](https://github.com/felixge/node-dateformat) too (I never tried this last one).

A second approach would be to use a datepicker like:

- a react component already embedding the date format, like [react-input-calendar](http://rudeg.github.io/react-input-calendar/) or [react-bootstrap-date-picker](http://pushtell.github.io/react-bootstrap-date-picker/).
- [jquery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: it s a text field which should allow the date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format....no date picker or jquery allowed...want to fix this using javascript

Comment: So momentJs should do the job. I used it to parse text field that was not filled as experted. With momentJs, you can declare a format and assrt the text field value is correct

Comment: I don't want to use any other js library. I want to handle this on keypress, which should allow only valid characters. for example, if my first text is 7 then it should to allow only "/" character, any other number to 7 will be an invalid date.

Comment: hum ok, in that case use `str.charAt(str.length - 1)` to get the last caractere of the textdfield value and verify it is fitting a number of a `/` (with a [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp)). Gook luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add onchange on input field and use the preg_match from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)
link

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone using redux and redux-form, there is a mechanism `Field Normalizing`
Check out details at [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/6.1.1/examples/normalizing/)